# Trying to avoid RBAR! How to correlate an insert on a related table as a set based operation?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005, set-based

Assume a schema that consists of the following tables:

**Baz**

```
BazID (PK, Identity)
Description
```

**FooTemplate** (A Baz may have zero to many FooTemplates)

```
FooTemplateID (PK, Identity)
BazID (FK)
Description
NextGenerationDate
```

**BarTemplate** (A FooTemplate may have zero to many BarTemplates)

```
BarTemplateID (PK, Identity)
FooTemplateID (FK)
Description
```

**Foo** (A Baz may have zero to many Foos)

```
FooID (PK, Identity) 
BazID (FK)
Description
```

**Bar** (A Foo may have zero to many Bars)

```
BarID (PK, Identity)
FooID (FK)
Description
```

Each day a stored procedure will execute to generate `Foo` and `Bar` entities for an associated `Baz` entity which have passed their next generation date.

The first part of this procedure looks a little like this:

```
DECLARE @GeneratedFooIDList TABLE (INT FooID);
INSERT Foo (BazID, Description)
OUTPUT inserted.FooID INTO @GeneratedFooIDList
SELECT
  BazID
  Description
FROM
  FooTemplate
WHERE
  NextGenerationDate < GETDATE()
```

My question is what statement can I now execute to generate the proper `Bar` entities and have them properly associated with the newly created `Foo` entities?

**EDIT:** The procedure will be executing on a server running SQL Server 2005.

**EDIT2:** Thanks to everybody for the help.  After considering the information carefully, I have opted for another solution.  I have changed the primary key in the Foo table to no longer be an automatically generated identity column, this way an intermediary insert into a temporary table could be executed to capture the relevant FooTemplateID along with the FooID

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your schema correctly

```
declare @GeneratedFooIDList table (FooID int, FooTemplateID int)
declare @Date datetime = getdate()

/*
insert Foo (BazID, Description)
    output inserted.FooID, FT.FooTemplateID into @GeneratedFooIDList
select
    FT.BazID,
    FT.Description
from FooTemplate as FT
where
    FT.NextGenerationDate < @Date
*/

merge into Foo using
(
    select *
    from FooTemplate as FT
    where
        NextGenerationDate < @Date
) as FT on 1 = 0
when not matched then
insert (BazID, Description)
values (BazID, Description)
output inserted.FooID, FT.FooTemplateID into @GeneratedFooIDList;

insert Bar (FooID, Description)
select
    G.FooID
    BT.Description
from BarTemplate as BT
    inner join @GeneratedFooIDList as G on G.FooTemplateID = BT.FooTemplateID
```

well, if you have SQL Server 2005, then this will not work. I can suggest another solution, by it will depends on uniqueness of combination `(BazID, Description)` in `FooTemplate` table. It also may be rewritten with variable table for fooTemplate with date < @Date if it helps.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ee576/29

```
declare @GeneratedFooIDList table (FooID int)
declare @Date datetime = getdate()

insert Foo (BazID, Description)
    output inserted.FooID into @GeneratedFooIDList
select
    FT.BazID,
    FT.Description
from FooTemplate as FT
where
    FT.NextGenerationDate < @Date

insert Bar (FooID, Description)
select
    G.FooID,
    BT.Description
from @GeneratedFooIDList as G
    inner join Foo as F on F.FooID = G.FooID
    inner join FooTemplate as FT on FT.BazID = F.BazID and FT.Description = F.Description
    inner join BarTemplate as BT on BT.FooTemplateID = FT.FooTemplateID
```

Comment: I receive an error when I attempt to execute that query.  I believe that the only two entities that can be referenced in an OUTPUT clause are inserted and deleted.  The reference to FT.FooTemplateID results in the following error:
The multi-part identifier "FT.FooTemplateID" could not be bound.

Comment: well yes, turns out that you can't use tables other than `inserted` in `INSERT` clause. So I've rewrited a query with `MERGE` insted. It's not very beutiful, but still it should work.

Comment: Thank you for the help.  This would work very well if not for the requirement that the solution must run on SQL Server 2005.  I'm sorry I did not specify that requirement sooner.  I have updated the question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

This makes the **big** assumption that there is only one FooTemplate per BazID, and only one BarTemplate per FooTemplate.  If this is not the case,
the structures make it hard to identify which baz goes with which foo templated, and which bartemplate goes with which footemplate -- you'd have to
toss in the Description columns to ensure uniqueness, and without PKs or UQs you can't be certain of uniqueness.

```
INSERT Bar (FooID, Description)
 select new.FooId, bt.Description
  from @GeneratedFooIDList new
   inner join Foo f
    on f.FooId = new.FooId
   inner join FooTemplate  ft  --  one to one assumption here
    on ft.BazID = f.BazID
   inner join BarTemplate bt  --  another one to one assumption here
    on bt.FooTemplateId = ft.FooTemplateId
```

As per @RomanPekar, if you could add the FooTemplateId in the temp table this later update would be simpler, but you are correct, the output clause only works on `inserted` and `deleted` (and it gets very fussy when you start dealing with new identity columns)

---

[Added]

Here’s how I’d summarize the core problem:

- You add many rows to the Foo table
- Each row has a freshly generated surrogate key (FooId)
- Zero or more Bar rows must now be generated for *each* of these new Foo entities
- So, each of your new rows must be mapped back to its original FooTemplate row, so as to get the "source" FooTemplate's necessary BarTemplate rows
- But, there is nothing in the Foo table to enable this mapping (e.g. to link Foo with its source FooTemplate. Can’t use BazId, because there could be multiple templates; can’t—well, shouldn’t—use description, because does not guarantee uniqueness
- Nor can this link be provided by the INSERT… OUTPUT… construct, as it can only extract columns inserted into the Foo table

One solution I’ve used in the past for this kind of problem is to *temporarily* populate a column in the new table (Foo) with the linking data. Here, I’d store FooTemplateId in Foo.Description, build the necessary INSERT…SELECTs based on that, and then updated Foo linked to FooTemplate on that id and replace description with the proper value. It works, but it is awkward.

An alternate solution, based on @MikaelEriksson’s unfortuitously deleted post and referenced links (especially [How I Learned to Stop Worrying and Love the MERGE](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/adam_machanic/archive/2009/08/24/dr-output-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-the-merge.aspx)
), is to use the merge command, which (who knew?) *can* reference columns outside of inserted and deleted in its output clause. Use that to populate the temp table with new FooID and source FooTemplateId, and work from there. (Without sample data to test and debug, I’m not confident enough in my MERGE skills to try and write this process, but I am confident that it could be done.)

Comment: @MikaelEriksson shows a work-around for the `OUTPUT` problem.

Comment: Thank you for the help!  The assumption that there will be only one FooTemplate per Baz or One BarTemplate per FooTemplate is not accurate.  Those are both one to zero-to-many relationships in the schema, though perhaps it would be best for me to be explicit.  I will update the question accordingly.  As such, this solution will not work.